# updating a sharepoint web app on mobile

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 site that has access web apps on the site.  I would like to be able to update the access database on a mobile device.  I have not found a way to make this happen.  Is there a way to be able to update the access database on a mobile device?

Comment: Can you clarify: do you mean that you would like to be able to change the access database data from either a webpage or app on your mobile device?

Comment: Yes, I would like to be able to edit and add data to the access database in the sharepoint site on a mobile device.

Comment: You will have to write an app that lets secure users edit database information, then just make that app public-facing so your mobile phone can access it.